# many-to-many mapping in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, many-to-many, xml-configuration

I'm looking to create a many to many relationship using NHibernate.  I'm not sure how to map these in the XML files.  I have not created the classes yet, but they will just be basic POCOs.

### Tables

**Person**
personId
name

**Competency**
competencyId
title

**Person_x_Competency**
personId
competencyId

Would I essentially create a List in each POCO for the other class?  Then map those somehow using the NHibernate configuration files?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can put the many-to-many relation to either class, or even to both. This is up to your domain model. If you map it to both, one of them is inverse.

```
class Person
{
  // id ...
  IList<Competency> Competencies { get; private set; }

  // you domain model is responsible to manage bidirectional dependencies.
  // of course this is not a complete implementation
  public void AddCompetency(Competency competency)
  {
    Competencies.Add(competency);
    competency.AddPerson(this);
  }
}

class Competency
{
  // id ...
  IList<Person> Persons { get; private set; }
}
```

Mapping:

```
<class name="Person">
  <id ....>
  <bag name="Competencies" table="Person_x_Competency">
    <key column="personId"/>
    <many-to-many class="Competency" column="competencyId"/>
  </bag>
</class>

<class name="Competency">
  <id ....>
  <bag name="Persons" table="Person_x_Competency" inverse="true">
    <key column="competencyId"/>
    <many-to-many class="Person" column="personId"/>
  </bag>
</class>
```

Only make it bidirectional if you really need it.

By the way: it is much better to write the classes first and create the database design afterwards. The database can be exported from the mapping files. This is very useful.

Comment: I guess I don't really understand why I would, or wouldn't, need bidirectional and what impact it haves if used when not really needed.

Comment: It depends on which property paths you need to "navigate" in your model. Do you regularly want to see the competencies of a person? Most probably you will, so it will be a good idea to have the competencies available in the person. Do you frequently need to know all the persons which have a certain competency? I guess this is an exception and could also be found by a query.

Comment: Shouldn't the name of the bag in the second class mapping be "Persons" and not "Competencies"?